# CSS positioning footer and distance between header tags

Tags: html, css, position, footer

how to keep my footer always at the bottom even when my content is less?
Decrease the distance between two heading tags? 
here is link to html and css  https://jsbin.com/guwugaloci/edit?html,css,output

img https://s31.postimg.org/hzkef0257/image.jpg

the problem is shown in the image and with the footer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please include your code appropriately and review [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

try absolutely positioning the footer

```
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
header{
  height:84px;
}
section{
  height:100%;
}

footer{
  height:84px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
 }
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<section>
  Content
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```